# Display NSProgressIndicator while filtering Realm

Tags: swift, realm

**Setup**:

A Swift 3 app, RealmSwift 2.10.1, with a single button, tableview and an indeterminate spinning progress indicator (the spinning circle)

**Goal**:

When the user clicks the button, query a large realm database (millions of records) and while waiting for the result, display the progress indicator.

**Issue**:

The progress indicator does not display until after the filter has completed.

**Code**:

```
//called from button click
func performFilterAction() {  
     self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
     self.filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
     let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", "US")
     let realm = try! Realm()
     self.results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(predicate)
     self.tableView.reloadData()
     self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
}
```

The above code filters Realm for all locations in the US and populates an array which is used as a datasource for a tableView.

**Other**:

The other issue is that even though the progress indicator is hidden at the end of the code, it does not hide in the UI.

I've tried implementing the filtering code on a background thread:

```
func performFilterAction() {
     self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
     self.filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {  
          let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", "US")
          let realm = try! Realm()
          self.results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(predicate)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
              self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
          }
     }
}
```

which does display the progressIndicator before filtering but crashes on the tableView reload with the following error

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

**Another Attempt:**

Per an answer provided I implemented collection notifications like this

```
func performFilterAction1() {
    self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
    self.filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", "US")
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(predicate)

    self.notificationToken = self.results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        guard let tableView = self?.filterTableView else { return }
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
            tableView.reloadData()
            self?.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
            break
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            break
        case .error(let error):
            // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
            fatalError("\(error)")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this: the progress indicator does not show  until *after* the filter completes, and it just 'blinks' on momentarily.

Per a request: A backtrace

```
772.00 ms   58.7%   0 s      Main Thread  0x72995
742.00 ms   56.5%   0 s       start
742.00 ms   56.5%   0 s        main
742.00 ms   56.5%   0 s         NSApplicationMain
625.00 ms   47.6%   1.00 ms          -[NSApplication run]
377.00 ms   28.7%   0 s           -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:]
342.00 ms   26.0%   0 s            -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:]
342.00 ms   26.0%   0 s             -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:]
342.00 ms   26.0%   0 s              -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:]
331.00 ms   25.2%   0 s               -[NSControl mouseDown:]
330.00 ms   25.1%   0 s                -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]
330.00 ms   25.1%   0 s                 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                  _os_activity_initiate_impl
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                   -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:]
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                    -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                     _os_activity_initiate_impl
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                      __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                       -[NSControl sendAction:to:]
319.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                        -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:]
318.00 ms   24.2%   0 s                         _os_activity_initiate_impl
259.00 ms   19.7%   0 s                          @objc FilterVC.filterAction(Any) -> ()
259.00 ms   19.7%   0 s                           FilterVC.filterAction(Any) -> ()
257.00 ms   19.5%   0 s                            FilterVC.test() -> ()
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                             Results.count.getter
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                              -[RLMResults count]
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                               -[RLMResults count]::$_1::operator()() const
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                                realm::Results::size()
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                                 realm::Query::count(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) const
238.00 ms   18.1%   0 s                                  realm::Query::aggregate_internal(realm::Action, realm::DataType, bool, realm::ParentNode*, realm::QueryStateBase*, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::SequentialGetterBase*) const
```

Comment: "The result of this: the progress indicator does not show until after the filter completes, and it just 'blinks' on momentarily." – I'd suggest breaking in the debugger immediately after tapping the button to initiate the action and taking a look at what the main thread is up to. That'll help you understand why the main thread is blocked. My suspicion is that you're accessing `self.results` somewhere prior to the initial notification being delivered, which would force the query to be evaluated synchronously at that point rather than being evaluated asynchronously as part of the notification.

Comment: One way to eliminate that problem entirely would be to defer assigning to `self.results` until after the `.initial` notification is delivered (i.e., assign to a local that's captured by your notification block, and only assign to `self.results` inside the notification block).

Comment: @bdash I appreciate the thoughts. I've done one better and eliminated self.results entirely and am using *let results =* within the function. I removed all references to the tableView so the only code in the entire project is what's in the question. There are no class variables at all and just the filterProgressIndicator which is shown when the button is clicked and hidden (per your code) in the notification block. Same result.

Comment: Ok, so what's the main thread doing when you tap the button? Presumably it's doing _something_ if you're seeing the UI become unresponsive. Capturing a backtrace or three in Xcode or using Time Profiler in Instruments will show what's going on.

Comment: @bdash Ran the Time Profiler several times. It's showing Realm occupying 90.1% of the main thread and also 25% of pthread_body. When the filter runs, CPU usage goes to 199%. The heaviest weighted functions are like realm::Query::aggregate_internal. Not sure what that means exactly but I would say the filter is tying up the main thread and preventing the UI from updating.

Comment: Can you please share the backtrace of the main thread up to `realm::Query::aggregate_internal`? Given the code changes you describe there's no reason that the query execution should be happening on the main thread. The backtrace should reveal what is forcing it to happen on the main thread.

Comment: Done. Updated the question with backtrace. There is one additional line of code in the app *let aCount = myArray.count*. That's just to see how many objects were found which in this case was 49905.

Comment: And it's that exact line of code that's forcing the query to be executed synchronously! Move it inside the `.initial` case of the notification and you should see the delay disappear. As I said earlier, _any access to `results` prior to the initial notification being delivered will force the query to be evaluated synchronously_.

Comment: @bdash Well I'll be. That's very interesting. I'll rework the code and let you know.

Comment: If you think about it, in order for `results.count` to give you a meaningful value it must first execute the query. Similarly for other operations on `results` that access information about the contained elements.

Comment: @bdash Yes! Makes perfect sense now with the detailed and on point explanation. Thank you for sticking with this to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [Realm's collection notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications). That'd look something like:

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
var results: Results<MyClass>? = nil

func performFilterAction() {
  filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
  filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

  let realm = try! Realm()
  results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter("location = %@", "US")
  notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
    guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
      // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
      tableView.reloadData()
      self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
      break
    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
      // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
      tableView.beginUpdates()
      tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                         with: .automatic)
      tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                         with: .automatic)
      tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                         with: .automatic)
      tableView.endUpdates()
      break
    case .error(let error):
      // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
      fatalError("\(error)")
      break
    }
  }
}

deinit {
  notificationToken?.stop()
}
```

This lets you display a progress indicator while the initial filtering is performed, and also provides animated updates as changes are made to the data in the collection. If you don't care about the latter you could instead just call `reloadData()` in the `.update` case as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I read about notifications in the documentation and the docs state the notifications are triggered by *objects that have been added, removed, or modified since the last notification* and *You’re notified about modifications whenever a property of an object in the collection has changed*. We are not modifying any objects - just reading them. I've implemented this into my code and the behavior is similar - the progress indicator does not appear until after the filter has completed. It almost seems the filter is blocking the UI until it's process is completed.

Comment: You're overlooking _Collection notifications are delivered asynchronously, **first with the initial results** and then again after each write transaction which changes any of the objects in the collection_. By showing the progress indication prior to registering for the notifications and hiding it once the callback is called with the initial results, you allow Realm to evaluate the query asynchronously. The only time you'll see the UI block in this scenario is if you attempt to access `self.results` prior to the initial results being delivered, as that forces Realm to filter synchronously.

Comment: Nope - not overlooking that at all! I was hoping it would be a solution but I've fully implemented and tested it with a similar result. I've added the modified code as you have suggested to the original question - can you take a look? Perhaps I am overlooking something in my posted code? There's nothing else in the project other than that code and the tableView delegate methods. One other interesting item to note: When I click the Filter button in the UI, it turns blue and stays blue until the filter has completed.

Comment: This is the answer. The key is *once the callback is called with the initial results, you allow Realm to evaluate the query asynchronously*. Bottom line is that if results is touched in any way after the filter is started, it becomes synchronous and locks the UI. It can only be accessed from within the results.addNotificationBlock closure

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit to my answer to clarify it further if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything visual that is triggered when self.result is changed (e.g. in a didSet )  ?  If you do, then that is probably what's causing the error in you second solution.

What you could do is send the loading process to the main thread, instead of a background thread (i.e. a hybrid of your first and second approaches) so that the progress indicator gets a chance to appear:

```
func performFilterAction() {
     self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
     self.filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

     DispatchQueue.main.async {  
          let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", "US")
          let realm = try! Realm()
          self.results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(predicate)
          self.tableView.reloadData()
          self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
     }
}
```

Note that, while this may work, it is not a good practice to run lengthy processes on the main thread.   Another approach could be to load the data in a background thread but place it in a separate variable that you assign to result, from the main thread, when it is completely ready.   This would work like your second approach except that self.result would not be assigned in the background but in the main thread.

```
func performFilterAction() {
     self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = false
     self.filterProgressIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {  
          let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", "US")
          let realm = try! Realm()
          let newResults = realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(predicate)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.results = newResults
              self.tableView.reloadData()
              self.filterProgressIndicator.isHidden = true
          }
     }
}
```